# Change Window Open Position

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code :

```
<button id="3" onclick="reply_click(this.id)">B3</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
window.open('http://kedaikopichat.blogspot.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=1400, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
}
</script>
```

Used in here : [beritakedaikopi.blogspot.com](http://beritakedaikopi.blogspot.com), click chat on the right.

**My problem is** : How to make padding from top .. I want to only show the chatroom and the webcam inside the pop up content. I do not want the header "Kedai Kopi CHAT & TV & WEBCAM" include. How to reposition the popup content?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the ugly popup, create an overlay DIV element *Lightbox* and use AJAX with jQuery to call the desired content by ID:

```
$("#overlayElement").load("http://kedaikopichat.blogspot.com #HTML3");
```

Comment: as you can see that popup is from different page, i do not want to include div inside main blog because it will make page load slow..

Comment: @airi, that's not true. your page will load as usually. the AJAX will perform a content `.load()` only after one clicks the `CHAT` button.

Comment: yes i know ... but to generate the div in the televison part need to reload all their data stream.. what i do for my television part .. it will reload all and hide.. only show when user click.. or maybe im wrong.. can you provide me any link related to this so i can learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by removing the spaces. Try

```
window.open('http://kedaikopichat.blogspot.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbars=0,menubars=0,resizable=1,width=1400,height=650,left=300,top=50');
```

From the [documentation for `strWindowFeatures`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open#Return_value_and_parameters)...

> The string must not contain any blank space, each feature name and value must be separated by a comma.

The value for `top` is how you position the top edge of the window.

Comment: ok.. right now it only reposition the outer popup.. what i want how to reposition  the contect of the popup.. i want padding top.. i do not want to see this header "Kedai Kopi CHAT & TV & WEBCAM"..i want it only show the webcam and chatroom